# Understanding the proof of theorem of correspondace between covering maps and subgroups of fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I'd like to understand the proof of the theorem of correspondace between covering maps and subgroups of fundamental group.

$\textbf{Theorem :}$ Let $X$ connected and semi-locally simply connected. Then $\forall \hspace{0.1cm} H < \pi_{1}(X,x) \hspace{0.1cm} \exists \hspace{0.1cm} p : E \longmapsto X$ covering such that $p_{*}(\pi_{1}(E,\tilde{x}))  = H < \pi_{1}(X,x)$, where $\tilde{x} \in p^{-1}(x)$, the covering is unique up to isomorphism.

$\textbf{First part of the proof :}$ Since $X$ is connected and semi-locally simply connected we know the existance of $q : \tilde{X} \longmapsto X$ universal covering of $X$. Since $Aut(\tilde{x},q) \sim \pi_{1}(X,x)$ I denote with $H < Aut(\tilde{x},q)$, the image of $H$ under that isomorphism.

Denoted with $E = \tilde{X}/H$ we have the following $\tilde{X} \overset{\pi}{\longmapsto} \tilde{X}/H = E \overset{p}{\longmapsto} \tilde{X}/\pi_{1}(X,x) = X$

With $p \circ \pi = q$. I'd like to prove that $p$ is well defined and that is a covering map.

I tried to take a evenly covered neighboorhood $U$ of $x \in X$. Since $q$ is a covering map, $q^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of open of $\tilde{X}$, then $\pi$ of this disjoint union should an open in $E$, since the quotient maps induced by groups are always open maps, but I don't how to proceed from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that deck transformations shuffle the disjoint opens in the preimage of an evenly covered neighborhood, so the quotient of these opens will also consist of disjoint opens homeomorphic to the neighborhood on the base, since the quotient just identifies the opens together on orbits.

Answer (score 1):

It is a more general result that if $X \overset{p}{\longmapsto} Y \overset{r}{\longmapsto Z}$  and $q : X \longmapsto Z$ are continuos function such that $r \circ p = q$, with $p,q$ covering maps, $r$ is also a covering map.

In the Theorem cited such $r$ denoted with $p$, certanly exists continuos and gives the commuting diagramm by the fundamental property of identifications, since $q$ is costant on the fibers of $\pi$.